# how to populate many to many values with groupings ( non-VBA )

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery

I am trying to generate a list of many to many values using Excel formula

```
There are 5 scenario 
1) Num1 : Num2 ( Many to 1 ) 
2) Num1 : Num2 ( 1    to Many ) 
3) Num1 : Num2 ( 1    to None ) 
4) Num1 : Num2 ( None to 1 ) 
5) Num1 : Num2 ( 1 to 1 ) 

What i have now : 
GROUPING    Number 1    number 2
1                       07666806
1           07612400    
1           07612415    
2           04245040
2                       04289135    
2                       04289143    
3           09592216    
4                       06655031
5           05256254    01515151


Expected output :
GROUPING    Number 1    number 2
1           07612400        07666806    
1           07612415        07666806
2           04245040        04289135
2           04245040        04289143    
3           09592216    
4                           06655031
5           05256254        01515151
```

I tried using vlook up with nested if conditions , it only works for a few scenarios

Comment: would you like to see an approach using power query (available in Excel 2010 and later versions) just wondering?

Comment: hi terry, i think i have to seek approval to install it. that would take some time .

Comment: meantime , i am seeking out for possible means via formula

Comment: It is a built in function of Excel 2010 and all later versions. No need to install separately.

Comment: oh i see ok ! =D  by all means

Comment: I suggest you to add PowerQuery to your tag so more PQ contributors can assist you.

Comment: Hi Terry , i have tried using MS access. have successfully churn out the expected output using a work around interim solution 

step taken : 
1) split the table into two , ( Group and Nbr 1  | Group and Nbr 2 ) 
2) link them via Group 
3) Query unmatched records 
4) compile all query into excel

Answer (score 0):

i have tried using MS access. have successfully churn out the expected output using a work around interim solution

```
step taken in MS access :
 1) split the table into two , ( Group and Nbr 1 | Group and Nbr 2 ) 
 2) link them via Group 
 3) Query unmatched records 
 4) compile all query into excel
```

Comment: Good to know it is solved by MS Access. The logic of solving it in Power Query is similar. You load the source table to the editor, create 3 copies of the 'query', in the first query remove `number 2` column and filter out `null` in `Number 1` column, in the second query remove `Number 1` column and filter out `null` in `number 2` column, in the third query remove `Number 1` and `number 2` column, and remove duplicated values in GROUPING column, then merge it with the first and second query consecutively, and done. Let me know if you still want to see a proper answer for it.